# need the sum of sub sql select but need variables within the sub select

Tags: sql, postgresql, jira

I'm building an SQL QUERY to an existing software (Atlassian Jira) and am not able to make any changes to the database.

We do have several Issues within Jira (table: jiraissue) which have a 0 to n worklog entries in a separate table (table: worklog). Each worklog has also an userid of the user which logged the work and the user is member of one ore more usergroups. Each of these Issues (table: jiraissue) is linked to another issue (within another jira project, but this is - I assume - not relevant for non jira experts) which corespondents as the "cost unit".

means we want to know how many work is logged on each "cost unit". therefore we need to have an query which returns all "cost unit's" and the time logged per usergroup on the linked issues. the last point is, that the "cost unit's" are market with an component to know which "cost unit's" belong together. therefore to display only the "cost unit's" which are relevant to the report-user the query is using the component for select this.

what I found out so far works quite well, but returns as many rows for the "cost unit" as there are linked issues, but I need the sum of all linked issues.

I somehow should be able to sum all the results from the subqueries, but these seems not to be possible. I also tried to work with the subselect statements after FROM, but then I'm not able to use jiraissue.id.

here is my actual query:

```
SELECT 
  myktr.pkey,
  myktr.summary,
  sum(worklog_dev),
  (SELECT 
    sum(worklog.timeworked) 
  from
    worklog 
  WHERE worklog.issueid = jiraissue.id 
    AND worklog.author IN 
    (SELECT 
      child_name 
    FROM
      CWD_MEMBERSHIP 
    where lower_parent_name = 'jira-team-sdqm')) AS worklog_sdqm,
  (SELECT 
    sum(worklog.timeworked) 
  from
    worklog 
  WHERE worklog.issueid = jiraissue.id 
    AND worklog.author IN 
    (SELECT 
      child_name 
    FROM
      CWD_MEMBERSHIP 
    where lower_parent_name = 'jira-productowner')) AS worklog_pm 
FROM
  component,
  nodeassociation,
  jiraissue AS myktr 
  INNER JOIN issuelink 
    ON (issuelink.source = myktr.id) 
  INNER JOIN jiraissue 
    ON (
      issuelink.destination = jiraissue.id
    ),
  (SELECT 
    sum(worklog.timeworked) AS worklog_dev 
  FROM
    worklog 
  WHERE worklog.issueid = jiraissue.id 
    AND worklog.author IN 
    (SELECT 
      child_name 
    FROM
      CWD_MEMBERSHIP 
    where lower_parent_name = 'jira-developers')) AS worklog_dev_table 
WHERE myktr.pkey IN 
  (SELECT 
    jiraissue.pkey 
  from
    jiraissue,
    project 
  WHERE project.id = jiraissue.project 
    AND project.pkey = 'KTR') 
  AND component.ID = nodeassociation.SINK_NODE_ID 
  and myktr.id = nodeassociation.SOURCE_NODE_ID 
  and nodeassociation.ASSOCIATION_TYPE = 'IssueComponent' 
  and component.cname = 'Project-Component' ;
```

do you have any suggestions to me?
fyi: we are working with postgreSQL.

best regards,
stefan

Comment: I would firstly recommend using a bunch of **(sub)views** with meaningful names to simplify this monster of a statement (unless you have some sort of strict rules that limit you from doing this). It's hard enough just understanding what it is exactly that you're trying to do (absolutely no sarcasm) and following the parentheses does not make this task easier.

Comment: Or create a [Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) example that we can play around with

Answer (score 1):

For your aggregation to work correctly, you will need to use the [`GROUP BY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)-clause in your main select:

```
...
GROUP BY component
...
```